# Race results in a tie, How do I list both names on pedestal?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement

I am using visual studio C# to create a race result form to then display the winners on a pedestal in order for 1st, 2nd, and 3rd place. My code currently is set to display an error message if a tie occurs. I want to change it so that instead of an error message, the names will just be added to the corresponding pedestal so that ties are allowed.

Here is my code for my "tie" section.

```
// if the runners have a tie
            if (time1 == time2 || time2 == time3 || time3 == time1)
            {
                // show error message
                MessageBox.Show("It's a tie! Let's race again to find the real winner!");
                trophyGroupBox.Visible = false;
                timeBox1.Text = "";
                timeBox2.Text = "";
                timeBox3.Text = "";
                firstPlaceLabel.Text = "";
                secondPlaceLabel.Text = "";
                thirdPlaceLabel.Text = "";
                timeBox1.Focus();
                return;
            }
```

Part of my other code for when a tie does not occur and the names are listed as normal is...

```
  // if runner1 is faster than runner2
                if (time1 < time2)
                {
                    // display second and third place winners
                    secondPlaceLabel.Text = runner1;
                    silverTrophy.Text = runner1;
                    thirdPlaceLabel.Text = runner2;
                    bronzeTrophy.Text = runner2;
                }
                else
                {
                    // display second and third place winners
                    secondPlaceLabel.Text = runner2;
                    silverTrophy.Text = runner2;
                    thirdPlaceLabel.Text = runner1;
                    bronzeTrophy.Text = runner1;
                }
```

And here is what it looks like without a tie (and with a tie I simply want to just add a runner's name to the corresponding pedestal as a second name.

[Race Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odl8W.png)

Comment: You can probably simplify this by putting the data in a list and sorting that list.

Answer (score 3):

This will get a little easier if you group the data for each racer into a class instead of having separate variables and just "knowing" that `time1` goes with `runner1`, etc.

Maybe something like this:

```
public class Runner
{
    public Runner(string runner, TimeSpan time)
    {
        Runner = runner;
        Time = time;
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public TimeSpan Time { get; }
}
```

And then instead of having three separate variables you can put them in a list:

```
var runners = new List<Runner>();
```

Otherwise, how complicated would this get if you wanted to add more runners?

If you didn't read anything past here, just putting your data into some sort of structure should make your life a whole lot easier.

Now that your data is a little more manageable it will be easy to query. For example, suppose you wanted to get all of the runners in the race from fastest to slowest:

```
var orderedBySpeed = results.OrderBy(r => r.Time);
```

or you just want the top three:

```
var orderedBySpeed = results.OrderBy(r => r.Time).Take(3);
```

But according to your question you also want to account for possible ties. That means that each possible position (1st, 2nd, 3rd) could have more than one runner. To do that you could use `GroupBy`:

```
var winnerGroups = runners.OrderBy(r => r.Time)
    .Take(3)
    .GroupBy(r => r.Time)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key); // this last sort may be redundant.
```

We're taking the fastest three and grouping them according to their time.

Now `winnerGroups` is a set of *groups* of runners. Each group has a "key", which is what they have in common. The key is the `Time`. So runners with the same `Time` are in the same group. In most cases no two runners would have the same time, so you would have three groups, each with one runner. But if two people were tied for first or second then that group would contain two runners.

These methods all use LINQ to query collections. If you haven't used much then one LINQ example after another can be a little bit fatiguing. But here's one more.

Suppose these are the results of the race, so that Bob and John are tied:

Bob - 1:00
John - 1:00
Steve - 1:05

This query:

```
var winnerNames = winnerGroups
    .Select(g => string.Join(" / ", g.Select(w => w.Name)));
```

will return an `IEnumerable<string>` containing

```
Bob / John
Steve
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will have a lot of if-else conditions if you implement it this way.  Something like this:

```
        if (time1 == time2)
        {
            if (time3 < time1)
            {
              timeBox1.Text = time1;
              timeBox2.Text = time2;
              timeBox3.Text = time3;
              firstPlaceLabel.Text = runner1+" and "+ runner2;
              secondPlaceLabel.Text = runner3;
              thirdPlaceLabel.Text = "";
              timeBox1.Focus();
              return;
            }
            else if (time3 > time1)
            {
              timeBox1.Text = time3;
              timeBox2.Text = time2;
              timeBox3.Text = time1;
              firstPlaceLabel.Text = runner3;
              secondPlaceLabel.Text = runner1+" and "+ runner2;
              thirdPlaceLabel.Text = "";
              timeBox1.Focus();
              return;
            }
            else
            {
              timeBox1.Text = time3;
              timeBox2.Text = time2;
              timeBox3.Text = time1;
              firstPlaceLabel.Text = runner1+" and "+ runner2+ " and "+ runner3;
              secondPlaceLabel.Text = "";
              thirdPlaceLabel.Text = "";
              timeBox1.Focus();
              return;
            }

        }
        else if (time2 == time3)
        {
            You get the idea
        }
```

In the long run, you will want to refactor your code so that you don't have to duplicate code like this. Follow the DRY principle :)